# Run Orion on docker in HTTPS

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

Hello again me ( sorry ),

I wanted to configure Orion which is running in docker to run on HTTPS.
Steps i took:

1. [Download script](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/test/functionalTest/httpsPrepare.sh)
2. Generate key and cert from it (localhost.key/localhost.crt)
3. Run cli command `contextBroker -https -key /localhost.key -cert /localhost.crt`

Additional info:

```
{
"orion" : {
"version" : "1.13.0-next",
"uptime" : "0 d, 0 h, 15 m, 56 s",
"git_hash" : "95ec3913f20682214891e92a5afbb0122293ffa2",
"compile_time" : "Thu Jun 14 11:03:03 UTC 2018",
"compiled_by" : "root",
"compiled_in" : "bfe336509e64",
"release_date" : "Thu Jun 14 11:03:03 UTC 2018",
"doc" : "https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/master/"
}
}
```

Error log after i enter cli command:

```
 lvl=ERROR | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=contextBroker.cpp[382]:pidFile | msg=PID-file '/tmp/contextBroker.pid' found. A broker seems to be running already
```

And more info:

```
root          1  0.0  0.6 383308 13592 ?        Ssl  08:31   0:00 
/usr/bin/contextBroker -fg -multiservice -ngsiv1Autocast -dbhost mongo
root        184  0.0  0.0   9096   868 pts/0    S+   08:54   0:00 grep -- 
color=auto contextBroker
```

Questions:
Have i made mistake in my approach to this, it seem that with my cli command i try to create another cb process and got error like this?

More info when i run this command:

```
/usr/bin/contextBroker -fg -multiservice -ngsiv1Autocast -dbhost mongo -https 
-key /localhost.key -cert /localhost.cert
```

I get this error:

```
time=Friday 15 Jun 09:25:20 2018.271Z | lvl=FATAL | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | 
from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=rest.cpp[1732]:restStart | 
msg=Fatal Error (error starting REST interface)
```

I know what this error mean because i saw u already respond to that on multiple posts, that there is 2 process using port and solution is killing one. But i see no such processes only from code above.
Hope this info helps on.

Thanks.

Update on 2 errors:

> PID-file '/tmp/contextBroker.pid' found. A broker seems to be running already

Removing old pid as u suggested solved this error.
I procede then with running cli command:

```
contextBroker -https -key /localhost.key -cert /localhost.crt
```

Then i checked:

```
ps ax | grep contextBroker
```

Output:

```
 1 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/bin/contextBroker -fg -multiservice -ngsiv1Autocast -dbhost mongo
90 ?        Ss     0:00 contextBroker -https -key /localhost.key -cert /localhost.crt
95 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto contextBroker
```

Netstat output:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1026            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN   
1/contextBroker
tcp6       0      0 :::1026                 :::*                    LISTEN      
1/contextBroker
```

Solution for people with similar problem.

```
mongo:
   image: mongo:3.4
   command: --nojournal
orion:
   image: fiware/orion
   volumes:
     - /home/igor/Fiware/Orion/localhost.key:/localhost.key
     - /home/igor/Fiware/Orion/localhost.pem:/localhost.pem 
   links:
     - mongo
   ports:
     - "1026:1026"
   command: -dbhost mongo -https -key /localhost.key -cert /localhost.pem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's have a look to the different errors:

> PID-file '/tmp/contextBroker.pid' found. A broker seems to be running already

This can be due to two reasons:

- Another Context Broker is running in the same machine using the same PID file
- Another Context Broker was running and it stopped in an unordered way (e.g. a crash) so it wasn't able to remove the PID file before stopping

Solution:

- Check no other Context Broker is runing in that machine (e.g. `ps ax | grep contextBroker`). If any, kill it.
- Remove `/tmp/contextBroker.pid` file if it exists.

> Fatal Error (error starting REST interface)

This error is tipically due to another process is using the same port that Orion (default: 1026). Check no other process is using it, e.g. using `netstat`. Typically this is due another instance of Orion has been previously started but it may be due to other causes.

Comment: I added new update to question. To summaries this is Orion running in docker so if i decide to kill it (ps ax | grep contextBroker), then it will exit instantly from container and close it. 

Could i set -https via docker-compose command option ( like -dbhost mongo ), or some external way.

Comment: I think that deserves another independent question at StackOverflow... something about "How to set CLI parameters in Orion docker?"

Comment: Thanks a lot for help i have add solution that worked for me hope it helps others.